# Browser extension to forward several emails at once through the Gmail interface

Tags: web-browser, gmail

It's [not possible](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/-PXf0aUqrB8) to forward several emails at once through the Gmail interface. I'm looking for a browser extension that can:

- forward several emails at the same time through the Gmail interface in a simple way (e.g. I select a few emails and click on some forward button, not by [creating ad hoc filters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPC0nsDY8_w))

and if possible:

- free
- works with Google Chrome
- doesn't slow down the Gmail interface

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Chrome extension [Multi Forward for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-forward-for-gmail/jjmdplljmniahpamcmabdnahmjdlikpm):

- gratis
- [quota of 100 forwarded emails per day](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/multi-forward-for-gmail/TYiyCZMrMJA)
- straightforward to use
- [Official forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/multi-forward-for-gmail)
- [Cannot forward the full thread, but only the last message of the thread.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/multi-forward-for-gmail/Ot2wCF2nYyw)
- Emails go through some third-party Google app.

---

Some screenshots from [maketecheasier](https://www.maketecheasier.com/forward-multiple-emails-gmail-chrome/):

[image]

[image]